# Wait for function response then change state in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I'd like to check if image exist or not in componentDidUpdate function, and return true or false.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.loadedGroup !== this.props.loadedGroup 
        || prevProps.loadedGroupErrors !== this.props.loadedGroupErrors){
            let image = false;
            if(this.props.loadedGroup.picture !== null){
                if(this.props.loadedGroup.picture.fullResolutionPicName !== undefined){
                        //image = true; //have to be true to print image - false showing placeholder
                        image = checkImage(apiPicturesUrl + this.props.loadedGroup.picture.fullResolutionPicName)
                 }
            }

        this.setState({loadedData: this.props.loadedGroup, 
            loadingGroupDataSpinner: false, loadedPosts: this.props.loadedGroup.posts ,
            showBackdrop: false, openEditPlace: false, openEditPlaceDesc: false, 
            bgImageLoadedSucces: image});        
    }
}
```

And my checImage function.

```
function checkImage(src){
var image = new Image(); 
image.src = src;
    if (image.width === 0) {
        alert("no image");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is a problem because that function is executed asynchronously, and when I'm checking img width it hasn't been updated so far even if there is an image.

How Can I write it correctly without `setTimeout`?

Comment: Did you try using `async / await` ? 
declare you lifecycle method like : `async componentDidUpdate(prevPorps)`
and then just `await` your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly - use `image.onload` event.

```js
// Replace this code
image = checkImage(apiPicturesUrl + this.props.loadedGroup.picture.fullResolutionPicName)

// with
image = new Image();
image.onload = () => this.setState({
// here you can be sure, that image is loaded, and set components state with data you need
});
image.src = apiPicturesUrl + this.props.loadedGroup.picture.fullResolutionPicName;

// Note, that it is important to have `onload` and `src` lines be written right in this order.
// First you register event handler, then you set the `src`
```